# Indeterminant numerical value of summation

Tags: numerics, numerical-value, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I have the following two-fold summation.

```
lim = 300;
Sum[((-1)^(n1 + n2) Gamma[5 + n1] (0.1)^(-1 - n1/5) (0.1)^(-1 - n2))/(
 5 Gamma[1 + n1] Gamma[29/3 + n1 + n2]), {n1, 0, lim}, {n2, 0, lim}]
```

which works fine and gives the correct numerical result `0.000577481`. But now if I increase the summation upper-limit to 400, then Mathematica shows Indeterminant and Complex Infinity encountered. This is not expected because no terms between lim=300 and 400 blows up.

This is a possible issue with internal default numerical precision. Hence, I tried to increase `$MaxExtraPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision` as follows,

```
lim = 400;
Sum[Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity, $MaxPrecision = Infinity}, 
  N[((-1)^(n1 + n2) Gamma[5 + n1] (0.1)^(-1 - n1/5) (0.1)^(-1 - n2))/(
    5 Gamma[1 + n1] Gamma[29/3 + n1 + n2]), Infinity] // Quiet], {n1, 
  0, lim}, {n2, 0, lim}]
```

But still, the same error persists.

Any reason for this behaviour, and what is the solution to this?

Comment: I think that `Simplify` might give a more stable version of your summand. Both your numerator and denominator are going to be very large.

Comment: You can use `1/10` instead of `0.1` and get an exact answer.  `N[answer, precision]` will give the decimal value to `precision` digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Instead of machine precision (0.1), use arbitrary-precision (0.1`20)

```
expr = ((-1)^(n1 + n2) Gamma[
      5 + n1] (0.1`20)^(-1 - n1/5) (0.1`20)^(-1 - n2))/(5 Gamma[1 + n1] Gamma[
      29/3 + n1 + n2]);

sum[lim_] := Sum[expr, {n1, 0, lim}, {n2, 0, lim}]

sum[400]

(* 0.00057748068405058200 *)

Precision[%]

(* 17.5845 *)

sum[500]

(* 0.00057748068405058200 *)

Precision[%]

(* 17.5845 *)

sum[Infinity]

(* 0.00057748068405058199972 + 0.*10^-24 I *)

Precision[%]

(* 20. *)
```

You can remove the imaginary artifact with [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)